# Rules to follow to create edges in graph

Tags: graphs

I am currently writing a graph object in Swift, I see that there are different types of graphs, some that are undirected and some that are directed. Here are my questions :

- Can a graph be both directed and undirected, is there a specific name for such graph?
- What is the common approach to make an edge that would be bi-directionnal but whose weight depends on the direction you are following. Would it be acceptable to make an edge that hold two weights, one for each direction? Or should I create two edges?

Thank you.

Comment: I have never seen anyone try to have an undirected edge whose weight is different in each direction. If you want that, use two directed edges.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you, I'll use directed edges than, especially since all the documentation online will use that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graph that is both directed and undirected is called a [Mixed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_graph).

All graph libraries that I know don't have direction dependent edge properties. Hence I would advise against introducing them if two directed edges do the job.